# Working with DBeaver encountering an issue where a only one of 2 tables is displaying in Database Navigator

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, dbeaver

- related article: [here is an article that appears to be closed for
  being an "irreproducible" issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6446)
- related article: [here is another    related article](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2624)

System information:

- Operating system (distribution) and version: Mac Catalina
- DBeaver version: 7.1.2
- Database name and version: Postgresql
- Driver name:    JDBC Driver for SQL Server
- Express Server
- VSCode

I am doing a simple migration of two tables to a database from a project in VSCode.  I have been viewing the database results in DBeaver.  It worked fine and as expected with the first migration I did.  I needed to add a foreign key and was able to do that successfully within DBeaver.  I then wanted to add it to migration file and had a syntax error when I migrated it.
I was going to use JOIN to link the two tables.

I had to change the SQL syntax of the migration and migrate it again. When I did that it it threw an error.  I re-migrated the original code that had worked before, without the error-prone syntax to create the tables again and it appears to have successfully created the two tables, but only one is showing in the Database Navigator.

I thought it was only creating one table but then found that both tables exist and can be accessed in the "Projects" window, but not the "Database Navigator" now.  They were showing there minutes before.  I thought the migration didn't work and then found that the tables were just not showing up in the Database Navigator.

Any ideas on how to get the tables to display correctly in the database navigator would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the database navigator and Projects windows with the noteful_notes showing but the noteful_folders table not showing:
[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHwmf.png)

Here is the code for my migration file I used ... it was called 001.do.create_noteful_folders:

```
CREATE TABLE noteful_folders (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    hex_id VARCHAR,
    title TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE noteful_notes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    hex_id VARCHAR,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    modified TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    folderId INTEGER,
    folder_hex_id VARCHAR,
    content TEXT
);
```

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on public --> Tables in the Navigator and clicking on Refresh?

Comment: That worked!  I was pressing refresh from the file menu and it wasn't working and tried right clicking refresh on the parent database...I needed to refresh from the public tables.  Thank you very much!